# Data studio - Google Ads connector - Campaign start date

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using Google Ads connector in Google Data Studio.

Is there a way to access campaign start date or end date?

Comment: Please add more details for others to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this field isn't available in the Google Ads connector.

Of course, you can upvote/suggest this feature for Google following the [instructions of this link](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7340016).